# how to activate the functions of a div in css after focusing in a textbox in asp.net?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, asp.net

I have a div with icon, and a textbox.

this is the code:

```
 <div id="Backtb1">
   <i class="fa fa-envelope" id="envelope" aria-hidden="true"></i>
 </div>
 <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" CssClass="TextButtons" runat="server"  placeholder="Username" ></asp:TextBox>
```

and the css for both Backtb1 and textbox1:

```
.TextButtons {
    position: relative;
    border: none;

    border-radius: 4px;
    width: 130%;
    height: 30px;

    font-family: Calibri;
    font-size: 120%;

    font-weight: bold;

    opacity: 0.6;
     border: 1px solid #888;
    background-color: #888;
    margin-bottom: 2px;


  -webkit-transition: width .35s ease-in-out;
  transition: width .35s ease-in-out;


}
.TextButtons:focus{
    width: 115%;
    outline:0;

    border: 1px solid;
    border-color: orange;
    opacity: 1;
}

#Backtb1 {
    position: absolute;

    top:0;
    left:0;
    opacity:0;
    width: 130%;
    color: white;
}
    #Backtb1:focus {
        background-color: orange;
        opacity:1;
    }
```

I am trying to call the Backtb1 events after textbox1 gets focus.
So, the Backtb1 should get the opacity to 1 after I click the textbox1.

how can this be done? just on css or should I use jquery or javascript?

EDIT: since Vishal Kumar Sahu wanted full page code. this is it:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Login.aspx.cs" Inherits="Dope.Login" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <link href="assets/CSS/LoginStylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="assets/fontawesome/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="assets/fontawesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <script type = "text/javascript">
          function displayNextImage() {
              x = (x === images.length - 1) ? 0 : x + 1;
              document.getElementById("img").src = images[x];
          }

          function displayPreviousImage() {
              x = (x <= 0) ? images.length - 1 : x - 1;
              document.getElementById("img").src = images[x];
          }

          function startTimer() {
              setInterval(displayNextImage, 7000);
          }

          document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function (event) {
              startTimer();
          });

          var images = [], x = -1;
          images[0] = "assets/Images/Image1.jpg";
          images[1] = "assets/Images/Image2.jpg";
          images[2] = "assets/Images/Image3.jpg";
          images[3] = "assets/Images/Image4.jpg";

          $("#textbox1").focus(function () {
              $('#Backtb1').css("opacity", "1");
          });

    </script>

</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div id="CenterContents"  onload = "changeImage()">
        <%-- write everything here --%>
              <%-- backgroundimage --%>
             <img id="img" src="assets/Images/Image3.jpg">

        <div id="Shadows">

        </div>

        <div id="CenterPanel">
            <div id="wot">

                <div id="Backtb1">
                    <i class="fa fa-envelope" id="envelope" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                </div>
            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" CssClass="TextButtons" runat="server"  placeholder="Username" ></asp:TextBox>

            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" CssClass="TextButtons" runat="server"  placeholder="Password"></asp:TextBox>

            <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" />
             </div>
        </div>


        <%-- dont write anything lower than this --%>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible with CSS-only using the [":focus hack"](http://vanseodesign.com/css/click-events/) when you switch the position of the textbox and the *backtb1*-div in the html code. Because you set an absolute position to *backtb1* this should be a possible solution for you.

Run the code snippet and you'll see the *backtb1* appearing and disappearing when the textbox gains/loses focus:

```css
#backtb1 {
    display: none;
    background-color: red; color: white; border-radius: 7px; 
    max-width: 100px; font-family: sans-serif; font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center; margin: 4px 0 0 0;
}
#textbox1:focus ~ #backtb1 {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<input type="password" id="textbox1">
<div id="backtb1">
    <i class="fa fa-envelope" id="envelope" aria-hidden="true">Got focus</i>
</div>
```

Comment: why when I add other functions to make the design cooler under display:none; it doesnt work.

Comment: @AltjenB. I just added text color red to the snippet - that works. What are you doing to make it look "cooler"?

Comment: @AltjenB. Added some more "cool" features - I cannot see a problem here.

Comment: sorry for the tame, I didnt put z-index: 3. but thanks for the code

Comment: hey, what about the  TextMode="Password"? it doenst work with the type of textbox you made. can you please tell me how you can fix it?

Comment: @AltjenB. Your question didn't mention a `TextMode` parameter. But my example should also work with a `<asp:TextBox>` (but not in the SO code snippet) as long as you keep the `id` parameter. Otherwise: I updated the sample and changed the textbox to `type="password"`.

Answer (score 0):

If they would have been adjacent (`+`) or parent child (`>`) then it was easy to do with CSS. But this time you need to it with jQuery as below-

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $( "#textbox1" ).focus(function() {
      $('#Backtb1').css("opacity","1");
    });
});
```

**Update**

Add this script to link jQuery to make the above code work.
`<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`

or better you can utilise [jQuery.toggleClass](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/).

Alternate suggestion for your problem is -

Just use
< asp : TextBox ID="TextBox1" CssClass="TextButtons" runat="server"  placeholder="Username" >

and have this CSS to make the envelope appear before the text box when input gets focus.

```
#textbox1:focus:before{
    content: "\f003";
  font-family: FontAwesome; /* Add relevant CSS */
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  display: inline-block;
  text-decoration: inherit;
}
```

Hope it will reduce few lines of code.

Comment: the code is easy to change, so can you please tell me how to do it in css?

Comment: @AltjenB. You tagged your question with `jquery` so why do you need a CSS-only solution?

Comment: I marked it because thought it wasnt possible to be done just with css @gus27.

Comment: Are you sure that jQuery thing is linked properly?

Comment: I added the jquery code under the javascript code (for other functions)
<script type = "text/javascript"> </script>

Comment: @AltjenB. It would be better if you provide HTML code rather than that `<asp:` thing, since CSS and jQuery work at client end.

Comment: @VishalKumarSahu I am developing the web in asp.net. not just html.

Comment: I uploaded the full page code with javascript too.. can you take a look at it please?

Comment: That is fine that you are developing it in ASP. But ASP has nothing to do with client end. HTML/CSS/JS are boss on front end.

Comment: I have updated the answer and you can get rid of `<div id="Backtb1">
                    <i class="fa fa-envelope" id="envelope" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                </div>`.

Comment: http://astronautweb.co/snippet/font-awesome/ has the full list of css content value. hope it helps.